# What MS licences would allow us to host client systems?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql, licensing

As I understand it, Microsoft licencing is tied to an organisation. My company is a gold partner and has volume licensing. We're toying with the idea of hosting some of our clients systems, but don't know whether our existing licensing allows that.
I've seen that SPLA licences allow for monthly billing, but do other licence packs, or even the purchase of a boxed product, allow you to run production environments for clients?
Also, is there a problem having multiple clients using a single Windows server, or SQL server?

Comment: If you are a “Gold partner”, you should have a contact at MS who can answer that for you. We can’t.

Comment: Yeah, our IT manager appears to be the only person with the contact details and is currently on leave. I was hoping it would be a fairly standard clause in the licencing... But it's an absolute minefield and I'm struggling to find details online